# Cannot install packages?

Tags: software-installation

I am a Linux newbie trying to setup Lubuntu 16.10 on my Dell desktop. This forum has helped me learn a good bit about Linux and Ubuntu in the last few days.

I'm now having trouble getting app packages to install and was wondering what I'm doing or not doing wrong.
I have a couple of applications I've downloaded, they are:

- VirtualBox-5.1_5.1.12-112440-Ubuntu-yakkety_i386.deb.
- audacity_2.12-1build1_i386.deb

When I try to install them, it opens software manager app, I click on " install and it does nothing. Doesn't confirm install, nothing seems to be added to the system. Then I back out of the software app and on the top of the window where it has 3 tabs - •All, •Installed, and •Updates I see under •Installed tab there is a blue 2 highlighted.
Also I am not connected to the internet and a message popped up saying a software update was needed to show all installed apps. Could this be why?

Comment: why aren't you using `sudo apt install virtualbox` etc?

Comment: @Zanna I do not know much about the command line

Comment: @JosephBeasley - Please see my answer, and if you don't know how to open a terminal, it's CTRL+ALT+T.

Comment: The Oracle-provided VirtualBox package has [some instructions to follow to install it properly](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads#Debian-basedLinuxdistributions) so that it will integrate properly with Apt.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of downloading the `.deb` files, you should let `apt` install them automatically for you.

First connect your computer to the internet, either via wifi or via an ethernet cable, so that it can get access to the packages you need.

Then, open a terminal and run these commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install virtualbox audacity
```

That should take care of it!

Comment: @ Android dev when I type  'apt install virtualbox '

Comment: I get ' reading packages list... Done ' ' building dependency tree ' ' reading state information ' '

Comment: E: unable to locate packages

Comment: Sorry. Phone keyboard.

Comment: @JosephBeasley - Does the same thing happen for `sudo apt install audacity`?

Answer (score 0):

Please PLUG-IN the ethernet cable and your problem should go away:*) The man stated in the Question that he gave us "Also I am not connected to the internet" You cannot recieve updates without internet connection:*)

Answer (score 0):

When you have a local .deb you can use this command to install it:

```
sudo dpkg -i name.deb
```

However you will need internet if the package has dependencies. And like the others mentioned it is always easier just to use apt-get or Ubuntu Software.